# install go-ethereum dependencies and tendermint dependencies with glide

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum, glide-golang, tendermint

I'm using "glide" to manage my go packages, here is my glide.yaml:

```
package: github.com/my-project
import:
- package: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
  version: 1.8.14
  subpackages:
  - cmd/utils
  - common
  - common/hexutil
  - consensus/ethash
  - core
  - core/state
  - core/types
  - core/vm
  - eth
  - ethdb
  - event
  - log
  - node
  - p2p
  - params
  - rlp
  - rpc
- package: github.com/tendermint/tendermint
  version: 0.23.0
  subpackages:
  - abci/types
  - libs/log
  - rpc/lib/client
- package: gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1
testImport:
- package: github.com/stretchr/testify
  subpackages:
  - assert
- package: github.com/tendermint/go-amino
```

when I run glide install, then some errors show up:

```
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/mattn/go-colorable
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/huin/goupnp
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp
[ERROR] Error scanning github.com/prometheus/prometheus/util/flock: 
cannot find package "." in:
    /root/.glide/cache/src/https-github.com-prometheus- prometheus/util/flock
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/elastic/gosigar
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/mohae/deepcopy
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/influxdata/influxdb
```

...

```
[ERROR] Error scanning golang.org/x/sys/cpu: cannot find package "." in:
/root/.glide/cache/src/https-github.com-golang-sys/cpu
[INFO]  --> Fetching updates for github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions to 3247c84500bff8d9fb6d579d800f20b3e091582c. 
[ERROR] Failed to retrieve a list of dependencies: Error resolving imports
```

so I try to change the glide mirror to my local file (I have cloned all the dependencies already), but it still not work, if someone know how to deal with it, please give me a hand, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, just set the mirror, and ignore some package, like this

```
glide mirror set https://golang.org/x/mobile https://github.com/golang/mobile --vcs git
glide mirror set https://golang.org/x/crypto https://github.com/golang/crypto --vcs git
....
```

ignore

```
- github.com/prometheus/prometheus/util/flock
- golang.org/x/sys/cpu
- golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack
```